# Popup div without resizing the parent

Tags: html, css

I've got follow code:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.isShown = false;

  $scope.togglePopup = function() {
    $scope.isShown = !$scope.isShown;
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
.inputAddon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
input {
  width: 75px;
  height: 19px;
}
.addon {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: green;
}
.popup {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" class="wrapper">
  <div class="inputAddon">
    <input type="number">
    <div class="addon" ng-click="togglePopup()"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup" ng-if="isShown"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, when I click on the green div, I would like to popup another div below the input and green div. At the moment this works, but it also resizes the parent div (grey). Who can I overlay it like this without resizing the parent:

[image]

I tried it with `z-index`, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks and cheers.

Comment: Just remove background color from .wrapper, and add it to .inputAddon!

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi But I would like to have an background-color on my .wrapper... so this would be more an workaround and would just look correct, but still resize my parent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: absolute` and `top` to the `.popup`:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.isShown = false;

  $scope.togglePopup = function() {
    $scope.isShown = !$scope.isShown;
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
.inputAddon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
input {
  width: 75px;
  height: 19px;
}
.addon {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: green;
}
.popup {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 32px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" class="wrapper">
  <div class="inputAddon">
    <input type="number">
    <div class="addon" ng-click="togglePopup()"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup" ng-if="isShown"></div>
</div>
```